# Configure Client Side SSL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, office-js

Is it possible to configure a self signed certificate inside of a Javascript app on the client side to verify a remote API?

My issue: I'm building an Office-JS App in Excel and it can only get/post etc to https URLs. My company SSL Cert is giving me errors during startup about "Revocation information unavailable". This doesn't happen in browsers though, only when using the Add-In. Rather then try to make changes company wide SSL, I'd like to configure the WebServer that hosts my JS Files for the Add-In w/ a self signed SSL certificate and have it act as an API proxy. All my requests from Office-JS would be to the same https domain the files are hosted in which would then reach out to other APIs over whatever method but not be constrained by Office-JS policies.

I've been able to generate SSL certs and import them to trusted store and then `get` via Axios, but I don't want to have to install the cert on each client, I'd like it to be stored inside the JS code that they load (I guess this initial load would have to be over http, then the requests would be https w/ the loaded certs?).

I've read a lot about using `https` agent in NodeJS but I think that is all server side stuff, I don't really use/understand NodeJS in the server sense, I just use it for NPM, but I use ISS in Visual Studio for Dev and prod I'll probably try and use NGinx as my Webserver on a linux host.

Is this even possible or am I just running myself in circles? Do I need to have the SSL installed into Cert Store on clients?